# Get product's final price with its selected custom option on add to cart

Tags: addtocart, quoteitem

I want just added product’s final price on “add to cart after” event. Here final price is in a term of, price with selected options (configured option, custom options). So how can I get this price?

I tried following codes to take final price but any of this is not working:

**Observer.php**

```
public function addtocartAfter($observer)
{
  $quote_item= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemByProduct($observer->getEvent()->getProduct());
}
```

**Or**

```
   public function addtocartAfter($observer)
    {
       $quote =  Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote();
       $quote_item  = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->load($quote->getItemByProduct($observer->getEvent()->getProduct())->getId());
    }
```

But when I tried to get price like : `$quote_item->getPrice()` .I got product’s price,without selected options's price.

Comment: can you please tell me,which is event.What you want final price of cart items or products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for this. Use the code given at below:

```
$item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
if ($item->getParentItem()) {$item = $item->getParentItem();}
$price = $item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice();
```

Comment: This should works only for configurable product. how can I achieve this  in Simple product with custom oprions?

Answer (score 1):

Get product's final price with its selected custom option on add to cart by below code

```
$item = $observer->getQuoteItem(); 
/* get configurable product's final price */
if ($item->getParentItem()) {
    $item = $item->getParentItem();
}
/* get configurable product's final price */
$price = $item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice();

$productOptions = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());

foreach ($productOptions['options'] as $key => $value) {

    $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($item->getProduct()->getId());
    foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) {
        $values = $o->getValues();
        foreach ($values as $v) {
            if ($value['option_value'] == $v->getOptionTypeId()) {
                $price  = $price  + $v->getprice(); /* get price of custom option*/

            }
        }
    }
}
```